# Adding numpy zero array and masked array

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have foll.. 2 numpy arrays:

```
arr_a = numpy.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
```

`arr_b` is second numpy array, but it is masked with mask value of `-9999.0`

if I do:

```
arr_a += arr_b
```

then the resulting `arr_a` does not retain the mask. How can I get an array in return that retains the mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `arr_b` is an instance of `numpy.ma.array`.  In such a case the semantics of numpy mean that `arr_a += arr_b` is adding the array **in-place**.  Thus, it certainly cannot alter its type from a `numpy.array` to a `numpy.ma.array`.

This is in contrast to `arr_a + arr_b` which is creating a **new** output array so is free to allocate it as it wishes.

If you wish to do an in-place add of a masked array, you must cast your target (`arr_a`) to be a masked array as well.

```
>>> arr_a = ma.asarray(arr_a)
>>> arr_a += arr_b
```

Comment: yes ... however if you are wanting to repeatedly do additions, bear in mind that in-place add's (`+=`) are more efficient as they do not require memory allocation.